# Как заставить устройство отправить ответ по заданному протоколу (реверсная инженерия)?

Tags: c++, linux, сеть, reverse-engineering, protocol

**Дано:**

Есть некое устройство - черный ящик, прямого доступа в его систему нет (скорее всего стоит линукс, но не факт, при загрузке выводит только свой логотип).

Известно, что устройство управляется по некоему стандартизированному протоколу и имеет свою имплиминтацию этого протокола.

Удалось узнать номера портов, по которым устройство слушает (5006) и посылает сообщения (5005) по этому протоколу.

Пробуем отправить по 5006 валидное с т.з. протокола сообщение. Соединение происходит, ответа нет (ни на одном из окрытых портов), реакции на самом устройстве нет. (соединялись через `netcat`)

При разрыве соединения устройство блокируется с упоминанием названия протокола и ничего нам не говорящими абравиатурами (что-то вроде `CS [ИМЯ_ПРОТОКОЛА] BLOCKED`. Повторное соединение не разблокирует устройство, только что помогает это **вкл/выкл**

**Найти:**

Каким образом можно узнать, что это вследствии того, что устройство хочет, чтобы с ним соединялись по `ssl` или проблема в невалидном запросе?

Какие вообще существуют хитрые приемы/инструменты для дальнейшего обратного инженеринга в подобных случаях?

**P.S.**

Производитель устройства был слит (фирма) с другим предприятием, большинство разработчиков этого устройства уволилось. В документации производителя по заданному протоколу информации ноль (номера портов удалось узнать через встроенный инструмент отладки доступному по одному из открытых портов), на практике управлялось до сего времени по другому устаревшему протоколу через ком-порт.

Comment: А какой бюджет этого хака? Не проще ли перекупить сотрудников, которые этот девайс программировали?

Comment: @VladD хотим выйти на человечка из  фирмы-клиента производителя, который знаком с этим аспектом, но здесь хотелось бы получить ответ в технической плоскости

Comment: Запись траффика и анализ в Wireshark уже пробовали?

Comment: `openssl s_client` не пробовали?

Comment: Непонятны два вопроса: 1) Почему Вы решили, что порты 5005 и 5006 - это порты SSL? 2) Что такое "валидное с т.з. протокола сообщение"? Какого - протокола? "Некоего, описанного в документации", или SSL ? Если речь идёт об SSL, то ведь там до прикладного протокола должна пройти аутентификация...

Comment: Как оффтоп. Если ничего не сказано в документации почему вы решили что канал поддерживается. Может этот канал технический для обслуживания/отладки.

Comment: @Sergey под "протоколом" имеется ввиду протокол прикладного уровня под транспортным уровнем `ssl`. Пусть это будет протокол П (суть не важно). Мы решили, что используется П под 5005/5006 можно сказать случайно. Подключились по одному из открытых портов и ввели `help` он открыл какую то командную строку (CLI) со списком доступных команд и каким-то виртуальным каталогом. По всей видимости это какой-то отладочный инструмент самих разработчиков. И вот в нем мы запустили один из доступных объектов (типа "файла" в каталогообразной системе команд) и получили информацию о назначении портов 5005/5006.

Comment: @Cerbo не решили - предположили. См. пред. сообщение

Comment: @Cerbo не решили - предположили (номера портов). В "панели администратора" есть окно настройки с именем этого протокола, правда там доступен только один пункт - ID устройства (он действительно требуется протоколом). То есть можно сделать вывод, что протокол поддерживается. Правда в самой документации по админ. панели это окно (или вкладка или подраздел) не упоминается. См. также пред. сообщение

Comment: Честно говоря - я запутался! Получается, что соединение по SSL установлено (5005/5006)? И аутентификация выполнена?
Подключились через что-то типа telnet? И Вы пытаетесь, ввести в консоли некую команду, предусмотренную протоколом П, но ответа не видите? Раз нет ответа - значит есть ошибка. Надо смотреть syslog. Вы же говорили, что можете подключиться через СОМ-порт, значит права root  у Вас есть. Если в логах ничего нет - выполните команду *netstat -l -A inet* - посмотрите, кто слушает этот порт.  Дальше ищите исходы этого модуля...

Answer (score 2):

**Закрываю** вопрос. Мы получили дополнительную документацию по конфигурации девайса (от человека, который с ним работал). Оказалось надо подключить флешку с файлами конфигурации в иксэмэл и в одном из таких файлов надо прописать айпи хоста. Самое плохое, что все эти файлы должны быть подписанны ЭЦП в специальном файле и, возможно, без валидной подписи не заработает, а без производителя сгенерировать подпись не удастся.

**P.S.** Проголосовал за закрытие, но он не закрылся, а стал требовать правки.

Comment: Если проголосовать за закрытие, вопрос объявляется требующим правки в надежде, что автор его улучшит. Через некоторое время вопрос закроется, если его не редактировать.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант - подключать сниффер в рабочую систему и анализировать проходящий траффик (искать поступающие команды и ответы системы).

Comment: Как-то слишком кратко для полноценного ответа, тянет скорее на комментарий. Хотя по сути всё верно и повторяет рекомендации про wireshark.